# Addition of values in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, addition, rows

I am fairly new to programming and C#. I am trying to add the values of certain columns for each row in my datagridview. The datagridview is not linked to any database, its value comes from the user input but have failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
double a,b,c,d,total = 0;

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        a = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Value);
        b = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[4].Value);
        c = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[5].Value);
        d = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[6].Value);
        total = a + b + c + d;
        MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need inner loop, remove it and you get solution

```
double a,b,c,d,total = 0;

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
        a = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Value);
        b = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[4].Value);
        c = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[5].Value);
        d = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[6].Value);
        total = a + b + c + d;
        MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. is there a way to not show the final messagebox as the value of the final row shows twice. thank you for your help

Comment: Above code shouldnt show last rows total twice. Do you have MessageBox.Show after loop?

Comment: No I don't, but in the datagridview, if I add in an input in one row, it automatically adds an empty row at the end. that's probably why it shows the last total value twice, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Yes you are right, if gridview addrow property open, then there will be open new empty row when you enter input value. You can check this by controlling every cell value, if all of them empty then dont show message

Comment: I fixed it a while ago by adding "if(!row.IsNewRow)" before initializing my variables. thanks for your help